# Calculate distance between two lat long and show in meters/ km using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to calculate distance between two latitude and longitude,if output distance less than km than show distance in meters like google map "190m";
as of now it is showing in miles

```
    <?php 
    function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    
      $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
      $dist = acos($dist);
      $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      $unit = strtoupper($unit);
      if($miles <1km){
echo 'away from'.$miles .'meters';// distance in meters

}
    
else{
echo 'away from'$miles.'km';
} 
    }
    
    echo distance('17.360527','78.473542','17.361012','78.473062','m');
    ?>
```

Comment: @NigelRen my question is if output value is less than 1km than show values in meters and output value is greater than 1km show as it is, but while converting this value km to meter I am not getting perfect output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think This will Works For You :

```
 <?php
       function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    
          $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
          $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
          $dist = acos($dist);
          $dist = rad2deg($dist);
          $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
          $unit = strtoupper($unit);

          // Convert Miles To KM 
          $dis_in_km = $miles * 1.609344;
          
            if($dis_in_km < 1){
                // Convert Miles to Miters
                $dis_in_m = $miles * 1609.344;
                echo 'away from '. round($dis_in_m,2).' meters';
            }else{
                echo 'away from '.round($dis_in_km,2).' km';
            } 
    }
    
    echo distance('17.360527','78.473542','17.361012','78.473062','m');
?>
```